# Using an expression tree to generate a select statement with a sum after a group by C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

Apologies if the question doesn't really make sense,

We use C#, Entity Framework & Linq for some context.

So the problem is:

A user can select a number of fields to be totaled up e.g. gross, net, vat across a data set, then when running a standard query to return the data the query has to total these columns for the search.

I'm trying to translate these statements into a dynamic expression tree.

```
List<string> propFrom = new List<string>()
{
   "Class1.PropertyName",
   "Class1.AnotherPropertyName"
}

Expression<Func<Grouped<Class1>, Class2>> select = (x => new Class2()
{
   Class1Prop = x.Sum(s => s.Class2Prop),
   Class1AntoherProp = x.Sum(s => s.Class2AnotherProp)
})
```

The properties on Class1 match Class2 and only the properties in the string list will be summed and selected in the select list.

I understand how to generate an expression tree for a standard select statement just not how to do one after a group by and using a sum.

If anyone can think on how to rephrase the question or any help as to the answer it is much appreciated.

-- Further Detail --

The application displays a table of data around invoices

Table looks something like this

invoiceNo,
Gross,
Vat,
Net....Other Fields

The table brings back all rows, the user can additionally say I wish to total any of the fields e.g. I want to sum up all vat and or all net, or just gross alone, problem is we don't know which of the fields they want totalling, if we did we could do

```
query.Sum(x => x.net)
```

but we have multiple sums of unknown columns so we're trying to use the property names to map to an a select statement as shown above

Data example,

```
invoices      Net      Gross    Vat
1             10       10       10
2             20       20       20
3             10       30       30
4             15       40       40
5             50       50       50
6             5        60       60
```

Users specifies total gross and vat there for get 
gross - 210, Vat - 210
along side all of their results

and yes the query groups by 1 to get the aggregate to calculate the sum, but thats done before e.g.

```
query.groupBy(x => 1).select(insertDynamicSelectHere);
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal example of input and desired output to clarify what you're after.

Comment: Is Class1 an entity, mapped to table in DB and Class2 is output? Does Class2 only contains sums and no other properties?

Comment: class 1 is indeed a table mapped to the db and class 2 is a DTO model matching class @AleksAndreev

Comment: Added more detail, hope it helps @phuzi

Comment: @BenJones so if you your table has only two colums "invoiceNo" and "Net" and user want to summarize "Net" - what should happens to "invoiceNo"? Should code do `GroupBy` by all non aggregating columns? Please add examples of input data and expected data result

Comment: So you need only sums in your DTO and all fields not mentioned in `propFrom` should be ignored?

Comment: Yeah @AleksAndreev

Comment: Your definition of `select` doesn't make sense to me - you say your input is `Grouped<Class1>` and your output is `Class2` but your output field is named `Class1Prop` and you are summing `Class2Prop` - do you have Class1 and Class2 backwards? And none of the property names match the `List<string>` - please clean that up.

Comment: How will you know that `Class2` has fields to hold the desired (dyamic) sums created based on the list of property names? Can you show some class definitions for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your requrement right, here is the code:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<IGrouping<int, TInput>, TOutput>> AggregateExpression<TInput, TOutput>(string[] strings) where TInput: new()
    {
        ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IGrouping<int, TInput>));

        // Create object using Member Initialization; for example `new XXX { A = a.Sum(b => b.A), B = a.Sum(b => b.B) }`
        MemberInitExpression body = Expression.MemberInit(
            Expression.New(typeof(TOutput).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)),
            strings.Select(CreateMemberAssignment).ToArray()
        );

        // Create lambda
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<IGrouping<int, TInput>, TOutput>>(body, p);

        // Create single member assignment for MemberInit call
        // For example for expression `new XXX { A = a.Sum(b => b.A), B = a.Sum(b => b.B) }` it can be `A = a.Sum(b => b.A)` or `B = a.Sum(b => b.B)`
        MemberAssignment CreateMemberAssignment(string prop)
        {
            // If needed you can map TInput.Prop to TOutput.Prop names here
            PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(TOutput).GetProperty(prop);

            return Expression.Bind(
                propInfo,
                Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.Call(
                        typeof(Enumerable),
                        "Sum",
                        new[] {typeof(TInput)},
                        new[] {p, CreateSumLambda(prop)}
                    ),
                    propInfo.PropertyType
                )
            );
        }

        // Create Lambda to be passed to Sum method
        Expression CreateSumLambda(string prop)
        {
            ParameterExpression q = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInput));
            return Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(q, prop), q);
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of calling

```
invoices.GroupBy(x => 1)
    .AsQueryable()
    .Select(i => new AggregatedInvoice
    {
        Net = i.Sum(x => x.Net),
        Gross = i.Sum(x => x.Gross)
    })
```

you can call

```
invoices.GroupBy(x => 1)
    .AsQueryable()
    .Select(LinqExtensions.AggregateExpression<Invoice, AggregatedInvoice>(new[] { "Net", "Gross" }));
```

For following models:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Net { get; set; }
    public decimal Gross { get; set; }
    public decimal Vat { get; set; }
}

public class AggregatedInvoice
{
    public decimal? Net { get; set; }
    public decimal? Gross { get; set; }
    public decimal? Vat { get; set; }
}
```

Method accepts 2 type parameters `TInput` and `TOutput`. You can use the same class for both if you want.
Only limitation is that both `TInput` and `TOutput` must have properties with same names.

Comment: Works like a charm, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking to do?

```
public class Data
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
}

public class DataContainer
{
    public IQueryable<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = MakeList();

        // Hardcoded
        var sumExpression1 = (Expression<Func<Data, Int32>>)(d => d.Value1); 

        // Generate property expression
        var sumExpression2 = GeneratePropertyExpression<Data>("Value2"); // THIS?

        // Generate Sum expression
        var sumExpression3 = GenerateSumExpression<DataContainer, Data>("Value3"); // OR THIS? 

        var selected = list.Select(c => new
        {
            Sum1 = c.Data.Sum(sumExpression1),
            Sum2 = c.Data.Sum(sumExpression2),

            // will not need the compile() if you generate the entire select expression.
            Sum3 = sumExpression3.Compile()(c)  
        }); ;

        var first = selected.First();
        var last = selected.Last();

        Console.WriteLine($"First().Sum1 = {first.Sum1}"); // 2
        Console.WriteLine($"Last().Sum2 = {last.Sum2}");   // 6
        Console.WriteLine($"Last().Sum3 = {last.Sum3}");   // 9 
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TParent, Int32>> GenerateSumExpression<TParent, TChild>(String field)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TParent), "c");

        // I don't know a cleaner way to get the LINQ methods than this. 
        // We use Enumerable because it wants a concrete type.
        var sumMethod =
        (
            from m in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            where m.Name == "Sum"
            let p = m.GetParameters()
            where p.Length == 2
                && p[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType
                && p[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
                && p[1].ParameterType.IsGenericType
                && p[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>)
            select m
        ).FirstOrDefault()
         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TChild)); // Enumerable is not generic, so we'll make it a generic with this reflection method. 

        var nestedLambda = GeneratePropertyExpression<TChild>(field);

        // 'parameter' is our DataContainer object, while 'Data' is the
        // property we want. 
        var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Data");

        // Null is the first parameter because it's a static extension method.
        var body = Expression.Call(null, sumMethod, prop, nestedLambda);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TParent, Int32>>(body, parameter);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, Int32>> GeneratePropertyExpression<T>(String field)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "d");
        var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, field);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Int32>>(body, parameter);
    }

    public static IQueryable<DataContainer> MakeList()
    {
        return new List<DataContainer>()
        {
            new DataContainer()
            {
                Data = new List<Data>()
                {
                    new Data() { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3 },
                    new Data() { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3 }
                }.AsQueryable()
            },
            new DataContainer()
            {
                Data = new List<Data>()
                {
                    new Data() { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3  },
                    new Data() { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3  },
                    new Data() { Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3  }
                }.AsQueryable()
            }
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah we can work out that bit but how do you then relate this back to the grouped object that is the parameter?

Comment: If you could maybe provide an example of the code you think will work, and where you are getting stuck I might be able to fill in the blanks better. System.Linq.Expressions is really powerful, but depending on what you need to do, sometimes you have to do a bit of overhead before you can make your expression (pulling property infos, types, methods, etc).

Comment: We don't have any code for after the group by, we can do a standard select e.g. get this param and field and bind it to the new model, thats fine but when you introduce a group by we have no idea unfortunately.

Comment: closest thing we have is the code in the question around turning that select into a dynamic expression

Comment: I updated my answer. Tell me if that's in the ball park of what you want to do...

Comment: Also updated it to show how to call the Sum method. If you're generating a select expression, you won't need the compile part (nor should you as this will force a query).